# Errors that occur when installing anaconda using Docker on M1 chip MacBooks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, anaconda, apple-m1

I tried to build an existing dockerfile on my MacBookPro with M1 chip, but I got the following error when installing anaconda3.
Why does it output such an error?
Also, how can I fix this?
In docker-compose, the platform is set to linux/arm64 and the cpus is 2, but the same error is output.

```
PREFIX=/opt/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile is below.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#update
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
sudo \
wget \
gcc \
g++ \
vim

#install anaconda3
WORKDIR /opt
#download anaconda package and install anaconda
# archive => https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
          
                sh /opt/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/anaconda3 && \
           
                rm -f Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh


ENV PATH /opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

#update pip and conda
RUN pip install -U pip

WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /
#execute jupyter lab as a default command
CMD ["jupyter","lab","--ip=0.0.0.0","--allow-root","--LabApp.token=''"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file is below

```
version: "3"
services:
  jupyter:
    image: investment-project:1.0.0
    container_name: investment-jupyter
    build: .
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    cpus: "2"
    volumes:
        - $PWD:/tmp/working
    working_dir: /tmp/working
    ports:
     - 8888:8888
    command: jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --LabApp.token=''
```

Comment: You're trying to install an x86_64 build of Anaconda. You need to find (or compile) an arm64 one.

Comment: AFAIK there is no anaconda for ARM yet. Why do you need it in Docker anyway? It is rather heavy, isn't it? If it is for jupyter there might be a way around.

Comment: @Siguza
Thank you I forgot that point. I will try to install from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases

Comment: @anemyte
I have a dockerfile that I used to use, and I want to use that file to build my environment using docker.